# Multicharacter-literal to char array

Tags: c++, char, hex, static-cast

I try making the multi character-literal to char array.

I know the static_cast and how multi character was calculated

but how do the result of multi character-literal is inserted to array.

follow the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a [] ={static_cast<char>('adcde')};
    cout << 'adcde' << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << a[3] << endl;
}
```

output:

```
1684235365
e\270\365\277\357\376
\277
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> char a [] ={static_cast<char>('adcde')};
> ```

This creates an array of 1 elements. The value of the element is the result of the cast. It will be some implementation defined value.

> ```
> cout << 'adcde' << endl;
> ```

This prints the multi character literal. It will be some implementation defined value.

> ```
> cout << a << endl;
> ```

This prints a character array. But because the array does not contain a null terminated string, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
> cout << a[3] << endl;
> ```

This accesses the array of 1 elements outside of bounds, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.